How VirtualBox NIC bridging works?
I'm trying to understand somethings.
General Part:
I'm new on this area and I saw a video of a phisical network that told that a bridge connects two networks and knows if certain host is on the A side or the B side. But:
How this works with virtual machines and/or containers?
Why if you set a VirtualBox Windows and set it to Bridge Mode it gets an IP on the Local Network, like, where is the bridge device? How is my NIC acting as a bridge device if it is using the internet?
Edit:
To understand better the answer, I reccommend seing:

this post to understand how VirtualBox driver works
this post to undestand how VirtualBox basic bridge flow works
this post to understand why most Wi-Fi adapters can't really bridge


The second half you've already posted in a separate thread yesterday, so I'll only answer the first half for now:

I'm new on this area and I saw a video of a phisical network that told that a bridge connects two networks and knows if certain host is on the A side or the B side.

Specifically, the term is used for "local" networks like Ethernet – and fully understanding its purpose probably needs remembering how old-style CSMA/CD Ethernet worked. When all hosts were connected to the same coax cable, all of them would physically receive everything from everyone else; a bridge would be used to partition such an ethernet in half.
In modern use, every Ethernet switch is a bridge and each port is its own "side", with the switch keeping track of whether a certain host is on port 1, port 2, or port 3 – but the actual term 'bridge' usually refers to software implementations (e.g. Linux virtual bridge interfaces) rather than switches.

Why if you set a VirtualBox Windows and set it to Bridge Mode it gets an IP on the Local Network, like, where is the bridge device?

Inside VirtualBox. It has an internal implementation of the full MAC bridging logic (i.e. a virtual Ethernet switch), which considers each VM to be a separate port and the physical NIC to be another port. This is not really made visible anywhere in the GUI, but it's there in the source code and is used for several of its network modes.
(It also has a full internal implementation of an IP router, which is used for its "NAT" mode.)

How is my NIC acting as a bridge device if it is using the internet?

The NIC is not acting as a bridge device in either case. It is acting more like a port of the bridge.
But in the case of VirtualBox, the rest of the system is unaware of the bringing being done; the additional "bridge driver" that VirtualBox installs will grab a copy of all Ethernet packets before the host OS gets to evaluate them, meaning that the host OS still only looks at packets directed to its MAC and ignores the rest, as before.
(Aside from that: a bridge can participate in the network it's bridging; it just needs to have an additional port internally. For example, an 8-port managed switch would really have 9 ports: eight physical, the ninth wired up internally to its management CPU.)

Much thanks friend! Just some questions before accepting:

So the correct term would be switch and not bridge like the old bridge devices?
If on bridge mode the physical NIC is acting as another port on a switch, how can the VM's use it to access internet, if it's just another device on a switch?
So in the case of virtual NAT the physical NIC is acting like a router an on a virtual bridge it is acting like just another device on a virtual switch?
In the case of VirtualBox, if you set the bridge mode, all the connections of your PC will first go through the bridge driver?


And, do you recommend any documentation/video to understand this? I've already saw some but still don't get how exactly this works, like why bridge mode doesn't works with some WI-FI NIC's.


Bridge is the general term, switch is one specific kind of bridge (I guess you could say it performs bridging by means of hardware packet switching, or something along those lines). 2) With the way VirtualBox does it, the interface doesn't lose any of its original functions – VirtualBox inserts a filter that grabs some packets and lets others pass through as usual. It's a bit different from the way Linux bridge interfaces work, but since it's all software, the same concept can be combined in various different ways – don't mix up bridge as a concept and bridge as a Linux-specific feature.


So yes, all packets go through the VirtualBox bridge driver that decides whether to intercept that packet and pass it to a VM or whether to let it go through normally. It also has some additional logic that lets it mostly work on Wi-Fi client interfaces, where pure bridging as Linux does couldn't work at all. As for NAT mode, the NIC still doesn't act as a router or anything other than a NIC – the "router" is again VirtualBox itself (whereas for Docker it would be the host Linux OS doing the routing... and with Docker on Windows, I haven't the faintest idea.).

Is there any documentation/video you recommend to understand all of this? It's not making sense for me

@Kobra I think bridging in VirtualBox works a bit like tcpdump and alike, that it "taps" at a NIC and more or less "copy" the frames received and flood/forward them to the VMs with the bridge implemented in itself ("userspace", I suppose). And for traffics from the VMs, it would by some means make them go to either the host or the link/network the NIC is attached to via the tap, based on whether the destination MAC address is the NIC's MAC address. (But this is really just random guesses / "deduction"; I suppose one would need to read the code of VirtualBox to tell exactly how it is done.)

@TomYan haha hello Tom, good to see you! Thanks mate, and sorry for making to much questions, but I'm just trying to understand how this works, because it's scrambling my mind for days. I've made a new post asking just about it, like, 1) Why some Wi-Fi adapters can't bridge and all Ethernet NIC's can. 2) How the router knows that the package need to be sent to the host, for it use the filter on the host and direct it to the VM. 3) Some people say that you need to stay on promiscuous mode to detect all traffict on the network and get those with the VM's MAC, but you can't sniff it on Ethernet.
